# Having trouble getting the highest to show

Tags: javascript

I need the highest value to display through a `for in` loop.
I got the three departments to display,but just after the `for in` loop It does not want to take in and give me the highest value.

So far the code loops successfully and gives me the required result. It should just `console.log` me the Outdoor as the department that's most profitable.

This is homework of mine,just too clarify cause I am not looking for an answer just clarification on how to do it. Simple and thorough.

```
var salesData = [
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 4500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 1500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 5500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7500, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 2505, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 1540, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 1500, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 8507, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 8009, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 12000, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 18007, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 6109, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7005, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 12006, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 16109, day : 'Friday'},
];

function mostProfitableDepartment(salesList) {
  //group by department`
  var salesForEachDepartment = {};
  var high = 0;

  //loop through all the sales
  for (var i = 0; i < salesList.length; i++) {
    //salesForEachDepartment += salesList[i];

    var deptDailySale = salesList[i];

    //check if the current department is in the salesForEachDepartment map
    if (salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.department] === undefined) {
      salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.department] = 0;
    }

    salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.department] += deptDailySale.sales;
    //deptDailySale.department
    //if ()
  }
  console.log(salesForEachDepartment);
}

mostProfitableDepartment(salesData);

for (var highestDepSale in salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.sales]) {
  if (salesForEachDepartment[highestDepSale.sales] > highestDepSale) {
    highestDepSale = salesForEachDepartment[highestDepSale.sales];
  }
  console.log(highestDepSale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should sort the salesList first before looping

```
salesList = salesList.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.sales - a.sales; // desc
});
```

Comment: it does not add new function, `sort` is already a javascript built-in function

Comment: Sorry I meant without those as well. @kiro112

Answer (score 0):

The structure of `salesForEachDepartment` is

```
{
  "hardware": 32505,
  "outdoor": 42525,
  "carpentry": 37267
}
```

So when you do `salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.sales]`, you are accessing only one value. Due to this, you are getting only first value.

You just have to use

```
for (var k in salesForEachDepartment) {
  if (salesForEachDepartment[k] > max)
    max = salesForEachDepartment[k];
}
```

**Your code updated**

```js
var salesData = [
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 4500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 1500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 5500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7500, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 2505, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 1540, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 1500, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 8507, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 8009, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 12000, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 18007, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 6109, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7005, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 12006, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 16109, day : 'Friday'},
];

function mostProfitableDepartment(salesList) {
  //group by department`
  var salesForEachDepartment = {};
  var high = 0;

  //loop through all the sales
  for (var i = 0; i < salesList.length; i++) {
    //salesForEachDepartment += salesList[i];

    var deptDailySale = salesList[i];

    //check if the current department is in the salesForEachDepartment map
    if (salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.department] === undefined) {
      salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.department] = 0;
    }

    salesForEachDepartment[deptDailySale.department] += deptDailySale.sales;
    //deptDailySale.department
    //if ()
  }
  console.log(salesForEachDepartment);

  var max = 0;
  for (var k in salesForEachDepartment) {
    if (salesForEachDepartment[k] > max)
      max = salesForEachDepartment[k];
  }
  console.log(max)
}

mostProfitableDepartment(salesData);
```

---

You can use `Array.forEach` + `for..in` + `Math.max`

```js
var salesData = [
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 4500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 1500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 5500, day : 'Monday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7500, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 2505, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 1540, day : 'Tuesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 1500, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 8507, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 8009, day : 'Wednesday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 12000, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 18007, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 6109, day : 'Thursday'},
  {department : 'hardware', sales : 7005, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'outdoor', sales : 12006, day : 'Friday'},
  {department : 'carpentry', sales : 16109, day : 'Friday'},
];

var groupedData = {}
salesData.forEach(function(o){
  groupedData[o.department] = (groupedData[o.department] || 0) + o.sales;
});

var max = 0;
for (var k in groupedData){
  max = Math.max(groupedData[k], max);
}
console.log(max)
```

Comment: Not actually what I was looking for. It should be a bit more simple.

Comment: Have you seen **your updated code**. Also *more simple*?

Comment: I tried the max and [k] as above mention it just tells me that salesForEachDepartment is undefined @Rajesh

Comment: Thats because I had moved that variable's declaration outside function. Since you are using 2 loops and you need it both, either define both loops in same function or declare variable outside

Comment: @Duvall912 I have moved `for..in` inside function. You can check it

Comment: So I can just change the if statement  in the for loop. to access the most profitable day ?

Comment: `If` and `object` to loop over `for..in`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127878/discussion-between-duvall912-and-rajesh).